# How to play a sound clip in JNLP?

Tags: audio, jnlp, playback, clip

I have the following line to play a sound clip :

```
Applet.newAudioClip(new URL("file:/C:/Dir_Sound/music.au")).play()
```

it works in standalone app, but in jnlp I got an error message :

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:/Dir_Sound/music.au read)

I'm not running it in "all-permissions mode", is there another way to play the sound file ?

PS : The sound file is selected by the user on his computer when the program runs, I can't embed it in my jar.

Answer (score 1):

Embed the file into your Web Start app.  Put a `<resources>` element with a jar in your JNLP file.  To access it, use [`getClassLoader().getResource`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).